# Creating custom image with Image Configuration Editor - Do I need to add hot fixes and security updates to my answer file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-embedded-7, answerfile

I am creating a custom Windows Embedded Standard 7 image, and I have run the Windows Embedded Developer Update tool to install updates and hotfixes to my distribution share.

When I open my answer file in ICE, the hotfixes and security updates are located under "Packages" in my DS. Do I need to add these to my answer file, or are they already installed and is my DS "patched"?

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in "Validate > Add Applicable Updates". These will then be installed during setup of Windows.